# Can non-US citizens own equity in US companies?

Tags: united-states, business, equity

Can a non-US citizen who has never been to the US own equity in a company that is only incorporated in the US?

Comment: This comment reminds me that there is a scam in which the scammer tells the victim that he is a foreigner who wants to invest in the USA and that he needs the victims'help (for a profit) to do it. This is always a scam; you can check some questions at [money.se].

Answer (score 13):

Yes, non-US citizens can own equity in US companies. To be specific: You do not have to be a citizen or resident of the US to own securities in a company incorporated in the US.

Comment: Though there may be limitations. I live in Canada and here you must have a minimum of 25% of shares being held by a Canadian resident or citizen. It seems reasonable the US has something simliar.

Comment: @corsiKa that seems a bit suspicious - for a publicly traded company, the % of shares held by various residents would change every day, and a Canadian public company traded on any major exchange can't prohibit all their stocks there to suddenly get traded to a nonresident (to be more precise, if they needed to prohibit that, then as far as I understand they wouldn't meet the conditions to be listed on that exchange); and of course most shares are not directly owned by citizens or residents of any country but by other institutions.

Comment: @corsiKa for a simple counterexample, Walmart Canada is an Ontario-registered company that's wholly owned by Walmart USA, which is in turn mostly owned by USA residents (the Walton family) and definitely not 25% by Canadian residents/citizens.

Comment: On the other hand, the 'Investment Canada Act' http://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/ica-lic.nsf/eng/home is quite interesting and probably would have applied to e.g. Walmart Canada.

Comment: @Peteris the question didn't specify publicly traded. I was assuming privately held corporations.

Comment: @Peteris it could work, but that would effectively mandate that no more than 75% of the stock in any Canadian based company be publicly traded.